# Upgrade from Prisma 3 to Prisma 4: RawQuery resulting Do not know how to serialize a BigInt

Tags: prisma

I'm using prisma@3.10.0 and works fine.
But when I'm upgrading to prisma@4, same code give me error like this:

> Do not know how to serialize a BigInt

Already read prisma [upgrading guide](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/upgrade-guides/upgrading-versions/upgrading-to-prisma-4#client-changes) but still not understand how do I need to upgrade my code?

```
export async function findMembers() {
  const members = await prisma.$queryRaw `SELECT * from members order by id ASC`

  return members;
}
```